# Laravel Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxxxxxxx" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel, smtp

I'm trying the reset password email controller in Laravel.
I change my MAIL config in .env file like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.aruba.it
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

I got this error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username 
"xxxxxxxxxxxx" using 2 possible authenticators. 
Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code 
"535", with message "535 5.7.0 ...authentication rejected ". 
Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code 
"535", with message "535 5.7.0 ...authentication rejected
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=<mailtrap username>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<mailtrap passsword>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL


signup https://mailtrap.io  after signin they provide demo inbox then click on demo inbox. right hand side you get your username & password. just copy and paste
```

Comment: which provider?

Comment: I would to connect to smtp.aruba.it, not to smtp.mailtrap.io

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.aruba.it
MAIL_PORT=465 or 25 
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxx      //in your aruba account. aren't they provided any password like mailtrap.
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL ot tls
i am not sure about this but you can try once
```

Comment: It's like my configuration. My provider, Aruba, give me username and password, but I got the error. My question is: what's that error ? What's means ? Is it an authentication problem ?